# How to update data in a table using dropdownlist box in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Im trying to make an orders table in PHP where i can choose in a dropdownlist box  the driver and the truck to each order from the existing sql db.
i managed to create the dropdownlist inside the table but i dont know how to update the db.
im trying using isset function but im probably not doing it right.

here is the code i made + a screenshot:

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAdWU.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Orders</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="table-general.css">
<style type="text/css">
 body
 {
  font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 90%;
  color: #666;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Orders</h1>
<a href="orders.php">Done</a></br></br>
<table class="general">
 <tr class="head">
  <th>Order_ID</th>
  <th>Customer_ID</th>
  <th>Driver_ID</th>
  <th>Truck_ID</th>
  <th>Date</th>
  <th>Project_Name</th>
  <th>Project_Place</th>
  <th>Amount</th>
 </tr>

 <?php
 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
 mysql_select_db("login");
 $result = mysql_query("select * from orders_table") or die("Failed".mysql_error());
 $result2 = mysql_query("select * from trucks_table") or die("Failed".mysql_error());
 if(mysql_num_rows($result2))
 {
  $select= '<select name="select">';
  while($record2=mysql_fetch_array($result2))
  {
   $select.='<option value="'.$record2['TruckID'].'">'.$record2['TruckID'].'</option>';
  }
 }
 $select.='</select>';
 while($record = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $record['Order_ID'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $record['Customer_ID'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $record['Driver_ID'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $select . "</td>";
  if(isset($_POST['select']))
  {
   $t=$_POST['select'];
   $sql = mysql_query("update orders_table set TruckID='$t' where Order_ID='".$record['Order_ID']."' ");
  }
  echo "<td>" . $record['Date'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $record['Project_Name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $record['Project_Place'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $record['Amount'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
 }
 echo "</table>";
 ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to learn something more about HTTP FORMS, how to send data from client to the server with POST or GET and how to use this data on the server with PHP.

see tutorials like these:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

In short - to send data from HTML page to the server, you need to wrap the inputs, selects, textareas in

```
<form action="url"> </form>
```

where url is pointing to your server php script, where your handling the form data

then you need to include

```
<input type="Submit">
```

which will generate a button on which when the user clicks the data are sent back to the server